# How to see which directory occupy the most disk?

Tags: centos

My disk is almost full, how can I know where takes away the most disk?

Because yesterday the disk is enough for my System.

```
[root@ha-node1 log]# df -lh 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        18G   18G  4.3M 100% /
devtmpfs        3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G   54M  3.8G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.9G  383M  3.5G  10% /run
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdc         20G   45M   19G   1% /mnt/sdc
/dev/sdb         20G   83M   19G   1% /mnt/sdb
tmpfs           781M     0  781M   0% /run/user/0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`du`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/du). Use `-x` to prevent recursion into other mount points. You can limit the output using `--max-depth=N`. Human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G) is enabled by `-h`.

Output can be sorted by piping to `sort`.

For example:

```
du -x --max-depth=3 -h / | sort -h
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend `ncdu`: https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu:

> Ncdu is a disk usage analyzer with an ncurses interface. It is
>   designed to find space hogs on a remote server where you don't have an
>   entire graphical setup available, but it is a useful tool even on
>   regular desktop systems. Ncdu aims to be fast, simple and easy to use,
>   and should be able to run in any minimal POSIX-like environment with
>   ncurses installed.

`ncdu` will present a list of directories sorted by their size, for example:

[image: https://dev.yorhel.nl/img/ncdudone.png]